# PostgreSQL WHERE cause to filter out results with 0 causes a syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to produce a SQL query where I have my IDs on the first column, then sum of page hits of accounts in column 2 and page hits of payments in column 3. The below code works, except for one point. I want to exclude any rows which have 0 in accounts column. When I add in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT
  EVAR3 AS MYID
  sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Accounts:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) as accounts
  sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Payment:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) as payments
FROM mytable
WHERE
timestamp >= to_timestamp('2021-09-01') AND timestamp <= to_timestamp('2021-09-02')
AND
(sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Accounts:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
GROUP BY EVAR3
ORDER BY EVAR3 ASC
```

This gives me an invalid expression error on my where clause saying generate expressions are not valid in the where clause. When I change WHERE to HAVING I get a syntax error saying it expected EOF rather than GROUP.

How do I correctly implement a filter to remove results with 0 in accounts to otherwise working code?

Comment: Update your post with a tag corresponding to the DBMS you're currently using.

Comment: Your question is missing both sample input and expected result as tables and as said the DBMS you use. Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm using postresql

Comment: Conditions on aggregates need to go into the HAVING clause. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-having/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an aggregate function it should be `HAVING` but it should appear after the `GROUP BY`. the structure is `SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY`

```
SELECT
  EVAR3 AS MYID,
  sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Accounts:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) as accounts,
  sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Payment:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) as payments
FROM mytable
WHERE
timestamp >= to_timestamp('2021-09-01') AND timestamp <= to_timestamp('2021-09-02')

GROUP BY EVAR3
HAVING (sum(case when web.Page.name = 'Accounts:Overview' then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
ORDER BY EVAR3 ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for that. If I copy your code but remove the HAVING line, it works (without the filter). When I add the HAVING line in as you have it, I get an error saying error code:42703 column evar3 does not exist. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I noticed Commas were missing from your original query. Maybe that's a DBMS thing but I believe I've never seen it. It is saying that EVAR3 is not a column within your table. maybe due to commas not separating columns out?